# Is it safe to assign positive values of ptrdiff_t to size_t

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I was trying to implement `strlen` function and I came across this implementation
in the [linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0585df468e8f4481b78256a2bf09449290bfcbf3/lib/string.c#L478):

```
size_t strlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *sc;

    for (sc = s; *sc != '\0'; ++sc)
        /* nothing */;
    return sc - s;
}
```

According to the C standard, the best fitting type for the operation `sc - s` is
ptrdiff_t.

Now in this snippet, `sc` is guaranteed to be greater or equal to `0`, which means
we don't have the risk of returning a negative type.

For positive values, is it safe to return `sc - c` as `size_t`? In other words, is it possible in
the real world, that an implementation has `PTRDIFF_MAX` greater than `SIZE_MAX`?

---

Here is my implementation of `strlen`:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s)
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while (*s != '\0') {
        size++;
        s++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: "*the best fitting type for the operation `sc - s` is ptrdiff_t.*" -- actually, the type of this expression **is** `ptrdiff_t` ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the assumption holds, but can't find proof in the standard right now, so not writing an answer here ... [tag:language-lawyer]-tag is obviously appropriate, adding it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, Yes I know :D, actually, I have seen some code where this kind of operations are assigned to `int`, and pointers assigned to `unsigned int`.

Comment: shorter and also correct: `size_t strlen(const char *s) { size_t sz; for (sz = 0; s[sz]; ++sz); return sz; }` \*scnr\*

Comment: @FelixPalmen, This one is pretty good :).

Comment: @J.W yes is great :D.  it is only two times slower. The strlen has to be performance optimized. seme strcpy, memcpy, memmove etc. https://godbolt.org/g/SJucLM **EDIT** Almost 3 times as instruction used by compiler are slower

Comment: @P__J__, absolutely, and builtin `strlen` can even deduce the value at compilation time for string literal ;) [https://godbolt.org/g/pUiikw](https://godbolt.org/g/pUiikw).

Comment: it is inlined as you have const value initialised with string literal. It should not have been counting at all. If it is less trivial: https://godbolt.org/g/DdwXNm

Comment: @P__J__, awesome, thank you for the information ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe if you pass valid object, because substraction of 2 pointers can only be done with pointers to same object.

> #### 6.5.6 Additive operators
>
> 9. When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>      or one past the last element of the array object**; the result is the difference of the
>      subscripts of the two array elements. ...

Since `sizeof` operator can at most return `SIZE_MAX`, expression `sc - s` can never return larger than that.

Comment: I read this very sentence earlier and didn't get to this now-obvious conclusion -- well done!

Comment: Would this still not suggest that a cast to `(size_t)` is appropriate in the OP's case?

Comment: @FelixPalmen may I invite you to read what I have to say on this?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to post a slightly different opinion than the current accepted answer for the sake of argument, not that this is too much of a noticeable problem in practice.

1. What is wrong in `return sc - s;` is not so much the implicit conversion from the `ptrdiff_t` type of the subtraction to the `size_t` return type as **the fact that `sc - s` can, according to the standard, overflow, and [it is undefined what happens when it does](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9)**.
2. This means that the reasoning in “expression `sc - s` can never return larger than [`SIZE_MAX`]” is wrong: the standard is worded so as to allow the actual difference between the pointers to be more than `PTRDIFF_MAX`, and then the subtraction invokes undefined behavior. When this happens, it doesn't matter that you could have represented the difference as a `size_t` because the eventual conversion to `size_t` does not undo the undefined behavior that happened during the `ptrdiff_t` subtraction.
3. This is only a worry in practice for 32-bit platforms where `malloc` allows to allocate blocks larger than 2GiB, and is effectively used to do so by the program. This is not the case, for instance, in the Linux kernel. When the Linux kernel is compiled for a 32-bit platform, the function `strlen` that is the subject of your question will never be called on a string that size.
4. If your implementation of `malloc` lets you create blocks of more than 2GiB, and you use that feature in your C programs, you are navigating a minefield even if you avoid subtracting `char` pointers more than 2GiB apart, because optimizing compilers assume that memory blocks are smaller than 2GiB for various optimizations, [even when the standard does not allow them to](https://trust-in-soft.com/objects-larger-than-ptrdiff_max-bytes/).

The standard also allows `PTRDIFF_MAX` to be larger than `SIZE_MAX`. On a platform where this were the case, the reasoning that the actual result of a pointer subtraction also needs to be less than `SIZE_MAX` and safely convertible to `size_t` would apply. (I have never encountered such a platform, all the compilers I know use the same width for `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t`.)

Comment: Quality implementations where objects's sizes can be larger than PTRDIFF_MAX should generally define the behavior of pointer addition and subtraction in such a way that `p+(q-p)` will yield `q` even if `q-p` overflows.  For the Standard to specify this would require that implementations where `q-p` could overflow must define not only the behavior of `q-p`, but must also define the behavior of adding an out-of-bounds value to `p`.  Rather than get into such details, the authors of the Standard figure that people writing quality implementations are capable of recognizing such things.

Comment: Your fascinating examples reinforce my belief that the standard really should precisely define pointer subtraction for two pointers into (or just past) the same object. Such a change should be less controversial today than it would have been a decade ago... But the worst examples come from the annoyingly unsafe malloc interface. Obviously it's too late to change malloc to a calloc-style interface. (And the standard doesn't make it clear whether calloc is supposed to definitely return NULL if nmemb*size overflows, and I think many implementations have UB in that case.) But it's OK to dream...

Comment: @rici Part of my job is to formalize the interfaces of standard C functions, and after much deliberation, we chose to make it a precondition of `calloc` that the mathematical product of its arguments is less than `PTRDIFF_MAX`. As in, you must prove that it is the case. This implies that the programmer who chose to use our tools is not allowed to let the arguments of `calloc` overflow and the call fail. It may look as this undoes the benefit of having two arguments to `calloc`, but interestingly, it doesn't. [continued]

Comment: With a single argument, the proof that the argument is less than `PTRDIFF_MAX` could in some cases be “too easy”, when the argument was the result of an unsigned overflow. With two arguments there is less risk of accidentally proving the wrong thing. (Of course the tools also make you prove that subsequent accesses are in-bounds, so that case of the unsigned overflow in the computation of the argument would be caught anyway, but it's always better to have the warnings as close as possible to where the bug needs to be fixed).

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, in the real world anything can happen, it just depends on how you want to use and deploy your application in the real world.

From experience, if you are doing something important with this code, and you wish to use it in the future, I strongly suggest implementing it robustly for all cases.

After reading [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) about ptrdiff, it seams this type was created to account for 64 bit systems.

If you don't account for special cases, you might have issues with portability on various platforms.

Now for size_t, the `"SIZE_MAX must be at least 65535"`, so that is the minimum you will find on all systems, and older systems might be limited.

From the [c type limit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) website, look at:

```
PTRDIFF_MAX    = +9223372036854775807
SIZE_MAX       = 18446744073709551615
```

So, yes, it can be a risk to use a different tried and tested implementation.

Comment: "*it seams this type was created to account for 64 bit systems.*" <- no, it was created to have a standard name for the implementation-defined integer type that is the result of subtracting two pointers.

Comment: and it can be deduced from the standard that such a difference can never be larger than `SIZE_MAX`, see the other answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted to say it was needed for 64 bit support, not that that it was its original purpose